# How to write in excel using java apche POI :showing java.io.IOException: Stream Closed error

Tags: java, excel, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

HI i want to write the result ot third column but it's showing stram closed error.

```
package test;


import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;

public class Xl2 {
public static void main(  String[] args ) throws Exception{
String[][] data ;
//HSSFCell cell = null;
data = excelRead();

String expectedtitle;
for (int i = 1; i < data.length; i++ ) {
expectedtitle = login(data[i][0],data[i][1]); 
System.out.println("page title after login is" + expectedtitle );
if(expectedtitle.equalsIgnoreCase(":: IRCTC :: - Plan My Travel")){

    System.out.println("PASS");
    String status="PASS";
    excelwrite(status);
    }
else{
    System.out.println("FAIL");
    String status = "FAIL";
    excelwrite(status);
    }
} 

} 

public static String login(String username,String password) throws InterruptedException{
//Step 1 Open Firefox
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
//Step 2 Go to url
driver.get("https://www.irctc.co.in/");
String actualtitle= driver.getTitle(); 
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,60);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("userName")));
Thread.sleep(3000);
driver.findElement(By.name("userName")).sendKeys(username);
driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys(password);


driver.findElement(By.id("button")).click();
   Thread.sleep(3000);   
   String expectedtitle= driver.getTitle();
   /*if (actualtitle.equals(expectedtitle)){
    System.out.println("FAIL" );

   }else{
    System.out.println("PASS" );
   }*/

   driver.close();
return expectedtitle;


}

public static String[][] excelRead() throws Exception {
File excel = new File("D:\\Work\\test2.xls");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(excel);
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
HSSFSheet ws = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");
int rowNum = ws.getLastRowNum() + 1;
int colNum = ws.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
String[][] data = new String[rowNum][colNum];
for (int i = 0 ; i < rowNum ; i++) {
HSSFRow row = ws.getRow(i);
for (int j=0  ; j < colNum ; j++){
HSSFCell cell = row.getCell(j);
String value = cellToString(cell);
data[i][j] = value;
// System.out.println("The value is" + value);


}
}
return data;

}
public static void  excelwrite(String status) throws Exception {
try{
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\Work\\test2.xls"));
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
    int LastRow = 0;
    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
    HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
    LastRow = sheet.getLastRowNum();
    LastRow = LastRow + 1;

    Row row = sheet.createRow(LastRow);

    Cell cell2 = row.createCell(2);
    cell2.setCellValue(status);
   file.close();
    FileOutputStream outFile =new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\Work\\test2.xls"));
    workbook.write(outFile);
    outFile.close();


}
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 } 
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (HeadlessException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}

public static String cellToString(HSSFCell cell) {
int type;
Object result ;
type = cell.getCellType();
switch (type) {
case 0 :
result = cell.getNumericCellValue();
break;
case 1 :
result = cell.getStringCellValue();
break;
default :
throw new RuntimeException("There are no support for this type of cell");
}
return result.toString();
}
}
```

Please help me out.My main intend is to extract value from excel and write the result(pass/fail) to their respective rows.I'm new to selenium and java.

Answer (score 2):

Hey i got the answer to my question.Hope it's useful for people who is new to this java excel area.

```
package test;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;

public class Excelreadwrite {


public static void main(  String[] args ) throws Exception{
String[][] data ;
data = excelRead();

String expectedtitle;
for (int i = 1; i < data.length; i++ ) {
int LastRow = i;
expectedtitle = login(data[i][0],data[i][1]); 
System.out.println("page title after login is" + expectedtitle );

if(expectedtitle.equalsIgnoreCase(":: IRCTC :: - Plan My Travel")){

    System.out.println("PASS");
    String status="PASS";
    excelwrite(status,LastRow);
    }
else{
    System.out.println("FAIL");
    String status = "FAIL";
    excelwrite(status,LastRow);
    }
} 

} 

public static String login(String username,String password) throws InterruptedException{

//Step 1 Open Firefox
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

//Step 2 Go to url
driver.get("https://www.irctc.co.in/");
String actualtitle= driver.getTitle(); 
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,60);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("userName")));
Thread.sleep(3000);

driver.findElement(By.name("userName")).sendKeys(username);
driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys(password);
driver.findElement(By.id("button")).click();
Thread.sleep(3000);   

String expectedtitle= driver.getTitle();

   driver.close();
   return expectedtitle;


}

public static String[][] excelRead() throws Exception {
File excel = new File("D:\\Work\\test2.xls");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(excel);
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
HSSFSheet ws = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");
int rowNum = ws.getLastRowNum() + 1;
int colNum = ws.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
String[][] data = new String[rowNum][colNum];
for (int i = 0 ; i < rowNum ; i++) {
HSSFRow row = ws.getRow(i);
for (int j=0  ; j < colNum ; j++){
HSSFCell cell = row.getCell(j);
String value = cellToString(cell);
data[i][j] = value;
// System.out.println("The value is" + value);


}
}
return data;

}
public static void  excelwrite(String status, int LastRow) throws Exception {
try{
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\Work\\test2.xls"));

    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
    HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

    Row row = sheet.getRow(LastRow);

    Cell cell2 = row.createCell(2);
    cell2.setCellValue(status);
    System.out.println(status);

    file.close();
    FileOutputStream outFile =new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\Work\\test2.xls"));
    workbook.write(outFile);

  }

   catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 } 
   catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
   catch (HeadlessException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}


public static String cellToString(HSSFCell cell) {
int type;
Object result ;
type = cell.getCellType();
switch (type) {
case 0 :
result = cell.getNumericCellValue();
break;
case 1 :
result = cell.getStringCellValue();
break;
default :
throw new RuntimeException("There are no support for this type of cell");
}
return result.toString();
}
}
```

EDIT:
Formating the code.

Answer (score 1):

You may also get this error if you call workbook.write( ) twice.

https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53515